# PHP parse XML url using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse a shoutcast XML url using PHP and simpleXML.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'http://api.shoutcast.com/legacy/stationsearch?k=mydeveloperAPIkey&search=fleetwood';
$stationlist = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
echo "<pre>" . print_r($stationlist) . "</pre>";

echo $stationlist->station[0]->name . "name <br>";
echo $stationlist->station[0]->mt   . "mt <br>";
echo $stationlist->station[0]->id   . "id <br>";

?>
```

print_r shows me this: http://sahanaya.net/kusal/1.php

how do I access the station name, mt, id, genre, ct, lc and others please ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Target URL return **Invalid parameter** error

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include an [mcve] - in this case, a small XML document with the same structure as the one you are processing, and the output you get running your code *with that document*. Please also make sure you've read [the basic examples in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and searched for related questions here.

Comment: @IMSoP thank you so much for the advice and guidance. While doing what you had asked I actually managed to solve my problem. What do I do now ? Delete the question ? Or answer my own question ?

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. You are [welcome to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you think it will help other people in future; if so, make sure the question is clear enough that people are likely to find it. If you don't think it would be useful to future readers, deleting the question is also an option.